# Preg_Match fetching all lines after a search word

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have the following html response:

```
   Your Balances: <br><br>Points Balance: 600.03<br>
   <br>Last Transaction(s)
   <br>01/11/2019 100050000000 Location1 $14.00
   <br>11/28/2018 100053700000 Location2 $10.50
   <br>10/03/2018 100051800000 Location3 $20.00
   <br>06/26/2018 100047400000 Location4 $17.50
   <br>06/04/2018 100046400000 Location5 $7.00
   <br>
```

I need to use `preg_match` to extract the all the text below the `Last Transaction(s)` part. What I have tried is the following but cannot get all the text:

**`preg_match('/Last.*Transaction\(s\)<br>((.)+)/',$input, $output);`**

but I only get a single line `01/11/2019 100050000000 Location1 $14.00` back.

Can anyone please assist in getting all the text as I specified above?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Try `s` (PCRE_DOTALL) modifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it with the `\G` flag like so:

```
(?:                             # non-capturing group
    \G(?!\A)                    # match after the last match
    |                           # or
    \QLast Transaction(s)\E\s+  # Last Transactions(s) lit. + whitespaces
)
\s*<br>\K                       # whitespaces + <br>, 
                                # "forget what's been matched thus far (\K)"
(?P<value>.+)                   # capture anything in that line
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/uB3I6v/1/) (and mind the modifiers!) but please note that parsing `HTML` (nested structures in general) is considered a bad practice. If possible, use a parser her.